# What data type should a date be set to and why?

Tags: excel, vba, date, variables, format

I was trying to assign a date to a variable. I tried:

```
Dim DateEnd As Date
DateEnd = 7 / 21 / 2019
```

This didn't work... So I tried:

```
Dim DateEnd As Date
DateEnd = Now
```

This works which meant that I am formatting the date incorrectly. So I set out to find how to format the date correctly. Surprisingly, this was not as easy to find as I thought it should be... But ultimately, I found a site:

```
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/dates-times/index.htm
```

It had several things that surprised me, for example it says:

```
"You should always try and store your dates in variables that have the Long datatype" and "Always declare dates as Long (never Date)."
```

My question is why?

It says:

```
"If a subroutine requires a Date datatype, pass in a Long instead and it will be converted automatically."
```

And it says:

```
"In VBA dates and times are enclosed between two hash (#) signs, for example: dtExpiries = #12/31/2006#"
```

So... After reading this (although I haven't tried it yet) I am expecting this to work:

```
Dim DateEnd As Date
DateEnd = #07/21/2019#
```

But it says I shouldn't do that... Instead I should do:

```
Dim DateEnd As Long
DateEnd = X
```

What do I put in place of the X? Just simply 07/21/2019?

Comment: `DateEnd = #07/21/2019#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub dates()
    Dim DateEnd As Date
    DateEnd = #7/21/2019#
    MsgBox DateEnd
End Sub
```

and if you start with a `String`:

```
Sub dates2()
    Dim DateEnd As Date
    Dim s As String

    s = "7/21/2019"
    DateEnd = CDate(s)
    MsgBox DateEnd
End Sub
```

Comment: My question is why does "https://bettersolutions.com/vba/dates-times/index.htm" recommend declaring dates as long instead of as date data type?

Comment: @XCELLGUY Normally it does not matter, but if you try to perform a `Match()` or `Vlookup()` from VBA, there is less chance for failure since you are comparing `Long` to `Long`

Answer (score 0):

*What do I put in place of the X? Just simply 07/21/2019?*

No, since you have declared `DateEnd` as a long, it will coerce the date value to a long.  `07/21/2019` will result in serial division --> `1.65098233448902E-04`

So in place of `X`, you can put the date constant: `#07/21/2019#`, or something else that will create a date.

As to the why of their recommendation, you should direct that question to the authors, but only after you have a complete understanding of how both Excel and VBA handle and store date data, so you can evaluate whether their recommendation makes sense for you.  Asking here will elicit a variety of opinions and is really off-topic.